# Google App Engine Latency skyrockets out of nowhere

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, latency

Our development team is scratching our heads wondering why Google App Engine latency tends to go through the roof from time to time with very little predictability or warning.  When latency jumps like this we start to see db timeouts between our app and database.  The CPU util is pretty flat across the instances at this time which also makes this hard to understand.

We are using the Flex environment to host a .NET Core API.  We like AppEngine for its PaaS feel and its always on feature.  We are thinking about looking at Cloud Run as an alternative to test with since we can't figure this out.

Any suggestions on where to look or how we could troubleshoot this?

Here's the latest spike in latency from last night. Plenty of Cloud SQL db timeouts and other exceptions happening here due to this [spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWpMp.png) as well.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reasons for this. This [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/troubleshooter/latency#determine_what_failed) has all the possible causes and  the debugging steps. Mostly check your monitoring for memory usage, there might be a memory leak. Also, check for the autoscalar configuration.